# use callback results as a variable outside of it node js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a function and get **info** undefined.

```
   var info =  queryCollection(t,where,type,function(result){
        var rek=result;
        return rek;
    });
```

code is in node js  on a server side with mongo db

Comment: queryCollection is an asyncrnous function (most likely). Hence the last parameter you provide is a callback. There is a lot of information out there that explains what this is and how to work with it.

Comment: @newBee would you please help to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking how one of the core concepts, asynchronicity, of javascript works. This is just out of scope for this platform and I would highly recommend to check out some tutorials before proceeding with whatever you are trying to build. This beeing said I've setup a small example.

https://jsfiddle.net/xavf01rn/

```
var myAsyncFunction = function(callback) {
     console.log("Now in async function...");
   // set timeout is an function that is async. E.g. like your queryCollection fundtion
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Passing back the result to the callback!");
        callback("dummyResultValue");
   }, 0) 
   console.log("Now exiting async function...");
};

// note how we pass in a function as parameter. It will be called once the async action has completed
var result = myAsyncFunction(function(asyncResult) {
   console.log("Got result in async function callback:", asyncResult); // asyncResult has a value
});

console.log("Result right after calling the myAsyncFunction function:", result); // result = undefined
```

Output looks like this which is most likely different from what you expect. This is due to the async nature of JS.

```
Now in async function...
Now exiting async function...
Result right after calling the myAsyncFunction function: undefined
Passing back the result to the callback!
Got result in async function callback: dummyResultValue
```

Try to understand why the output looks like it looks. Once you understood this: Yay! You know got familiar with one of the most important JS concepts that make the language so powerful (among other reasons).

Comment: but still result is undefined

Comment: Thats correct. But the result is known in the callback function. This is how JS works. What you are trying to achieve is not possible (except with bad programming style) with async functions.